# Is there a numpy function which takes from each line i of a matrix an element on the column y[i] and puts them all into an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

So basically, I need a numpy function which will do this or something similar to this:
`correct_answers = np.array([scores[i][y[i]] for i in range(num_train)])`
but using numpy, because Python list comprehension is too slow for me
scores is a num_train X columns matrix and y is an array of length num_train and takes values from 0 to columns - 1 inclusive
Is there a workaround using arange or something similar? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
y = np.arange(81).reshape(9, 9)
correct_answers = y[np.arange(9), np.arange(9)]
```

output:

```
y = 
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17]
 [18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26]
 [27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35]
 [36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44]
 [45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53]
 [54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62]
 [63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71]
 [72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80]]
correct_answers = 
[ 0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80]
```

Comment: And what if I want to not take only from the diagonal? For example, y = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] in the case of a 9x9 matrix (that would be taking the 0th element from the 0th line, the 0th element from the 1st line,..., the 0th element from the last line)

Answer (score -1):

`correct_answers = scores[np.arange(num_train), y[np.arange(num_train)]]`
This does the thing I wanted to do, props to the other dude which gave me the idea

Comment: `scores[np.arange(num_train), y]` may be enough.